# How to prove formally that $\emptyset\in \tau$

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem.** Let $X$ be a  non-empty set and $\tau\subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ defined by, $$\tau:=\{U\subseteq X: (\forall x\in U)(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq U]\}$$ is a topology on $X$. where $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfying the following properties,
>
> - $(\forall x\in X)(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B]$.
> - $(B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B})\land (x\in B_1\cap B_2)\implies (\exists B_3\in \mathcal{B})[(x\in B_3)\land(B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2)]$

When we were proving this we said that $\emptyset\in\tau$ **vacuously**. But when I checked the [Wikipedia article on vacuous truth](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCrM7w9OfNAhXKpI8KHRLwAqQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FVacuous_truth&usg=AFQjCNH9VzrurG7k98On9cyHmTQepiH1Sw) I found that,

> Statements that can be reduced (with suitable transformations) to this basic form include the following universally quantified statements:
>
> - ${\displaystyle \forall x:P(x)\implies Q(x)} $, where it is the case that ${\displaystyle \forall x:\neg P(x)}$.
> - ${\displaystyle \forall x\in A:Q(x)}$, where the set ${\displaystyle A}$ is empty.
> - ${\displaystyle \forall \xi :Q(\xi )}$, where the symbol ${\displaystyle \xi }$ is restricted to a type that has no representatives.

The questions I have are the following,

1. Do we $\color{red}{\text{define}}$ a statement to be vacuously true if it can be written in any one of the above three forms? If not then what *exactly* is the formal definition of a vacuous truth?
2. How can we prove from this definition that $\emptyset\in\tau$ is vacuously true?

**My Attempt**

To me it seemed that we can prove that $\emptyset\in\tau$ by using the second criteria but I am not sure what my $Q(x)$ would be. From the definition of $\tau$ we have, $$U\in\tau\iff (\forall x\in U)(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq U]$$Now if we substitute $U=\emptyset$ then we get, $$\emptyset\in\tau\iff (\forall x\in \emptyset)(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq \emptyset]$$ and if we want to write this in the form of second criteria, we get, $$\forall x\in\emptyset((\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq \emptyset]\iff\emptyset \in \tau)$$ which implies that $Q(x)$ is $(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq \emptyset]\iff\emptyset \in \tau$. But I am not sure, whether I am right. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think of "vacuously true" as a particular kind of truth in the sense that one should *rigorously prove* something is "vacuously true." Instead, you try and prove something is true (for instance, $\varnothing \in \tau$) and find yourself saying, "Oh, huh, there was really nothing to do there, but notice that a statement of the form "$\text{False} \implies \text{Who cares}$" is true by definition."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no formal definition of "vacuous truth".  It is just an informal term used to describe a commonly encountered flavor of argument.  When you "prove that something is vacuously true", the word "vacuously" is really describing the *method* you used to prove it, rather than the intrinsic "truth" of the statement.

The way you cast the statement as being vacuously true has the right idea, but you're taking things way too formalistically.  To say that "$\emptyset\in\tau$ is vacuously true" just means that you can prove $\emptyset\in\tau$ by proving it is a consequence of a statement of one of the types listed by Wikipedia (or another similar type of statement).  You have done that: $\emptyset\in\tau$ is equivalent to the statement $$(\forall x\in \emptyset)(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq \emptyset]$$ which is exactly the second form with $Q(x)=(\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq \emptyset]$.

Comment: So basically what we are doing here is to show that a statement of the form $\forall x\in \emptyset: Q(x)\iff \emptyset\in \tau$ and since the left hand statement is vacuously true the left hand statement should also be (since they are logically equivalent). What was the mistake I was making in considering $Q(x):=((∃B∈\mathcal{B})[x∈B⊆∅]\iff \emptyset\in \tau)$?

Comment: Well, if you choose that $Q(x)$, then you get a "vacuous" proof that $\forall x\in\emptyset((\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[x\in B\subseteq \emptyset]\iff\emptyset \in \tau)$.  But this statement is not what you actually want to prove; what you want to prove is $\emptyset\in\tau$.  So your "vacuous" statement should be chosen such that you can easily deduce the truth of $\emptyset\in\tau$ from it.

Comment: But considering the $Q(x)$ which I was considering, can't we say $\forall x\in\emptyset:Q(x)\iff \emptyset\in\tau$ (admittedly "vacuous", but I just want to know whether it is possible)?

Comment: I'm not sure what youre parentheses convention is.  If you mean $\forall x\in\emptyset:(Q(x)\iff \emptyset\in\tau)$ then sure, this is true (vacuously) but it doesn't allow you to conclude that $\emptyset\in\tau$ is actually true.  If you mean $(\forall x\in\emptyset:Q(x))\iff \emptyset\in\tau$, then I don't see how you're getting this equivalence.

Comment: @user170039 The sentence $ \forall x\in U\;(Q(x))$ is an abbreviation for $\forall x\;(x\in U\implies Q(x))$. The negation of that is $\exists x\;(x\in U\land \neg Q(x)).$ When $U=\emptyset ,$ that becomes  $\exists x \;(x\in \emptyset \land \neg Q(x))$, which cannot be true unless some $x\in \emptyset.$  Which isn't possible .So the negation of the original sentence is a falsehood.

Comment: @user254665: How the negation of $\forall x(x\in U\implies Q(x))$ is $\exists x(x\in U\land \neg Q(x))$? Shouldn't it be $\exists x(x\in U\implies \neg Q(x))$?

Comment: @user170039 The negation of $\forall x \;(S)$ is $\exists x\; (\neg S).$. ..And $A\implies B$ is an abbreviation for $(\neg A)\lor B.$ The negation of $A\implies B$ is therefore $A\land \neg B$ . In particular when $A$ is $x\in U$ and $B$ is $Q(x)$ and $S$ is $A\implies B.$......

Comment: @user254665: Oh yes. You are right. I missed that.